# When wrapped in MeteorJS cordova HowlerJS sound doesn't play on android

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, coffeescript, howler.js

sound can be heard fine on a mac chrome, on iOS safari and app, on android chrome, but on android app (both on actual device and emulator) it just doesn't produce any sound at all.
sound.playing() returns true.

example code (coffeescript):

```
sound = null

Template.playerPage.onCreated ->
   path = "/meditations/filename.mp3"

  sound = new Howl {
    src: [path]
    html5: true #it behaves the same with html5: false too
  }

Template.playerPage.events {
  'click .player-play': (e) ->
    sound.play()
}
```

any clues on what could be going wrong?
I was thinking about paths, but they seem to always be "/meditations/filename.mp3" in all the environment in which sound actually works, so I wouldn't think it's that

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add in the permissions to play sound:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Or faster:

```
meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.media@0.2.16
```

Hope it helps, have not personally tried it. I'm not sure how `Howl` works. If it uses `Media` under the hood it should be fine

Comment: I had done meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.media@0.2.16 and it didn't change the behaviour above

as for the lines you quoted, in which file should they be in?

thank you very much for your answer!